# Many popup errors when saving intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I get many pop up errors like so :

Failed to upload action package to AOG (preview)
Request contains an invalid argument.
The query pattern '$SchemaOrg_Number:numberx $SchemaOrg_Number:number2x $SchemaOrg_Number:number3' contains an undefined parameter (name: 'number2x' type: 'SchemaOrg_Number')

when I try to save my intent.

However when I navigate to test my google action , it seems to be working fine (it recognises the parameters when I give my application the same expression structure that I define in my training phrases)

It shouldn't be a problem , but I would like to submit my app for alpha testing, and when I do so I get an error of a similar nature:

The query pattern '$SchemaOrg_Number:numberx $SchemaOrg_Number:number2x $SchemaOrg_Number:number3' contains an undefined parameter (name: 'number2x' type: 'SchemaOrg_Number')

What is causing this error and how can I try and fix it?

Cheers!

Comment: How many Intents and Entity types have you defined? Do any of them include anything labeled "number2x"?

Comment: I haven't created any of my own entities , I'm just using the system ones.
I have one intent of my own, which contains 3 parameters number, number2,number3

Comment: I also have 2 follow up entities , from the aforementioned one. a yes and a no follow up